# Element not clickable when using FindElement on another WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a weird problem:

When I locate an element via:

```
WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div1"));
WebElement e2 = e1.findElement(By.xpath("//.[@class='c2']"));
e2.click();
```

I can't click e2, because: "Element < div class="c2" > could not be scrolled into view."

BUT when I locate e2 via:

```
WebElement e2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div1//.[@class='c2']"));
e2.click();
```

it works. (Also when checking `e2.getLocation()` the coordinates are different, and only correct in the second snippet).

I think Selenium doesn't like the "//.", because:

```
WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div1"));
WebElement e2 = e1.findElement(By.xpath("div[@class='c2']"));
e2.click();
```

also works.

Any idea how I can use the any (`.`) selector there? (`.[@class='c2']` can not be found)

[EDIT] I already have e1 and therefore need to search on this element via `e1.findElement(...)`

Comment: The dot is to select the current node. `//` denotes ANYWHERE in the path. Therefore, I think using `//.` is wrong. Instead, try with a single slash `//div1/.[@class='c2']`. I think that should work.

Comment: @hfontanez this ofcourse works when using it in one statement, the problem is that I already have e1 and only can search inside it. `e1.findElement("/.[@class='c2']")` does not yield any element unfortunately

Comment: I am trying to make you understand why `//.` doesn't work. And since you already have the web element, using dot to refer to it is pointless. Instead of trying to figure out who to use the dot selector for this specific problem, try to figure out the solution regardless of what the final Xpath expression looks like.

Comment: the "class" or style may be shared... so you might be getting two different webelements there.  The one that works has a more defined path-based selector.  No need for two lines there, just create one XPATH for the element you are targetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebElement e2 = e1.findElement(By.xpath("//.[@class='c2']"));
```

this is same as finding element as `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//.[@class='c2']"));`

because you haven't given current node as reference

you should be using :

```
   e1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='c2']"));
```

## See the '.' in front of // , this means the current or reference node is the parent if you just use "//" instead of "//" it will search from the root

Comment: Ah okay, I always thought that `FindElement` on another element always changes the context to that element. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Great answer. I would also warn about the use of asterisk as it could malfunction if more than one element in the current path meets that criteria.